# Stopped polling job due to exception: System.MissingMethodException: UnityEditor.VersionControl.Task

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, resolver

I was following https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/start.
I've downloaded Google Mobile Ads Unity `Plugin v3.18.2`.

After importing it and setting up my device for android i came to this **error**. It happened after Play Service Resolver did auto resolve.

I've tried to do the same steps on 3 different devices, I had the same results.

Could anybody help me with it?

> Stopped polling job due to exception: System.MissingMethodException: UnityEditor.VersionControl.Task UnityEditor.VersionControl.Provider.Checkout(string,UnityEditor.VersionControl.CheckoutMode)
>     at Google.ProjectSettings.Set[T] (System.String name, T value) [0x00024] in /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/ProjectSettings.cs:119 
>     at Google.ProjectSettings+c__AnonStorey2.<>m__5 () [0x00000] in /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/ProjectSettings.cs:154 
>     at Google.ProjectSettings.SavePreferences (Google.ProjectSettings+SettingsSave saveLevel, System.Action saveToProject, System.Action saveToEditor) [0x00035] in /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/ProjectSettings.cs:135 
>     at Google.ProjectSettings.SetBool (System.String name, System.Boolean value) [0x00014] in /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/ProjectSettings.cs:153 
>     at GooglePlayServices.SettingsDialog.set_UseJetifier (System.Boolean value) [0x00000] in /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/SettingsDialog.cs:225 
>     at GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver.CanEnableJetifierOrPromptUser (System.String titlePrefix) [0x00179] in /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:2270 
>     at GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver.ResolveUnsafe (System.Action`1[T] resolutionComplete, System.Boolean forceResolution, System.Boolean isAutoResolveJob, System.Boolean closeWindowOnCompletion) [0x00012] in /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1610 
>     at GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver+<ScheduleResolve>c__AnonStorey1E.<>m__40 () [0x00000] in /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1579 
>     at GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver.ExecuteNextResolveJob () [0x00069] in /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1438 
>     at GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver.ScheduleResolve (System.Boolean forceResolution, System.Boolean closeWindowOnCompletion, System.Action`1[T] resolutionCompleteWithResult, System.Boolean isAutoResolveJob) [0x000a7] in /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1592 
>     at GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver.AutoResolve (System.Action resolutionComplete) [0x00017] in /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1113 
>     at GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver.m__48 () [0x00016] in /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1092 
>     at Google.RunOnMainThread.ExecutePollingJobs () [0x0004a] in /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:300 
>   UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
>   Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecutePollingJobs() (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:303)
>   Google.RunOnMainThread:m__17() (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:414)
>   Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction(Action) (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:234)
>   Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll() (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:406)
>   UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes v3.18.2 has issue with Resolver, Try this one

https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/releases/tag/v1.2.124

Comment: After updating my unity to version 2019.2.0f1. Downloading unity-jar-resolver-1.2.124 and GoogleMobileAds-v3.18.2 my issue went away. Thank you